# Can'd find the required library (shared or static) to resolve undefined references

Tags: c++, mongodb, cmake, shared-libraries, mongo-cxx-driver

Just tried the following code similar to [mongocxx C++ API Sample](https://mongocxx.org/mongocxx-v3/tutorial/)

```
#include <iostream>

#include <mongocxx/instance.hpp>
#include <mongocxx/uri.hpp>
#include <mongocxx/client.hpp>
#include <mongocxx/stdx.hpp>

#include <bsoncxx/json.hpp>
#include <bsoncxx/builder/basic/document.hpp>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    using bsoncxx::builder::basic::kvp;
    using bsoncxx::builder::basic::make_array;
    using bsoncxx::builder::basic::make_document;

    mongocxx::instance instance{}; // This should be done only once.
    mongocxx::uri uri("mongodb://localhost:27017");
    mongocxx::client client(uri);

    auto db {client["test"]};
    auto collection {db["books"]};

    return 0;
}
```

and I added the following three statements to CMakeLists.txt

```
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC
    /usr/include/
    /usr/local/include
    /usr/local/include/mongocxx/v_noabi
    /usr/local/include/bsoncxx/v_noabi
    /usr/local/include/libbson-1.0
)

target_link_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
    /usr/local/lib/
)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
    libmongocxx.so
    libbsoncxx.so
    libmongoc-1.0.so

    libsasl2.so
    libicuuc.so
    libssl.so
)
```

I tried building the project, but all I got was this:

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libicuuc.so.66, needed by /usr/local/lib/libmongoc-1.0.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libmongoc-1.0.so: undefined reference to `u_strFromUTF8_66'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libmongoc-1.0.so: undefined reference to `usprep_close_66'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libmongoc-1.0.so: undefined reference to `u_strToUTF8_66'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libmongoc-1.0.so: undefined reference to `usprep_prepare_66'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libmongoc-1.0.so: undefined reference to `usprep_openByType_66'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I can compile and add libicuu myself, but I don't know what libraries I should add to get rid of the undefined references (`u_strFromUTF8_66`, `usprep_close_66`, `u_strToUTF8_66`, `usprep_prepare_66`, `usprep_openByType_66`).

What library defines `u_strFromUTF8_66`, `usprep_close_66`, `u_strToUTF8_66`, `usprep_prepare_66`, `usprep_openByType_66`?

P.S. My OS is Ubuntu 22.04.

I tried running the code in Qt Creator.

Comment: I think `libicuuc` is a Unicode library. I think all your unresolveds are Unicode functions. Therefore I guess that when you link with that lbrary all your unresolveds will become resolved.

Comment: The message tells you that: "libicuuc.so.66, [...], not found". So you need that lib, possibly linked in **after** the mongoc lib.